# Running Python's IDLE in windows

Tags: python, windows, python-idle

I messed up my IDLE shortcut. What is the way to start IDLE from the cmd.exe shell in Windows?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On my system, running `C:\Python26\lib\idlelib\idle.py` launches idle from the command prompt.  Obviously you will need to adjust your path if your main Python directory isn't `C:\Python26\`.

It looks like you could also launch it via `idle.pyw` or `idle.bat` in that same directory.

Comment: Yes, when you install the python.org version it associates *.pyw with pythonw.exe on Windows so using that shortcut works. It also adds an "Edit with IDLE" context menu on Python sources (so it's also possible to start it by that devious way...). What I don't understand is why the Start menu shortcut doesn't simply show the target...

Answer (score 2):

You can just add a path in your Environment variables tab in My Computer Properties --> Advanced as `c:\Python27\Lib\idlelib`. After adding this path just write `idle.pyw` in `cmd` whenever you want to run IDLE.

Just make sure you replace the folder name with whatever directory name you have.